# emacs/evil-mode: How to make C-i work as "evil-jump-forward" when c-mode activated and work as "org-cycle" when org-mode avtivated

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I have activated evil-mode of emacs(version: 25.0.95.1).

What I need is: 
when c-mode activated, the key 'C-i' work as "evil-jump-forward".
when org-mode activated, the key 'C-i' work as "org-cycle".

When should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Just bind it to a command that tests the mode and invokes the command you want. Use the mode variable to test the mode: `org-mode`, `c-mode`.